# get additional value from form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

my form and controller below. basically I'm trying to obtain the form value mode in the controller, the cmd value is always set but my mode isn't set and i don't know how to obtain the value, can anyone tell me how to get it? 
or how to get it using the same method as the cmd string?

Thanks

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddEditRecord", "Equipment", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",OnSuccess = "onSuccess()", LoadingElementId = "dvLoading" }))
{    
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div id="equipmentDialog">    
    @Html.Hidden("hidMode", Request.QueryString["mode"].ToString())
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>
        @if (ViewBag.IsUpdate == true)
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        }
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MachineName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MachineName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MachineName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssetNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AssetNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetNo)
        </div>
        <p>
            @if (ViewBag.IsUpdate == true)
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="btnUpdate" name="cmd" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" />
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Add" id="btnSave" name="cmd" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" />
            }
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btncancel" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

my addedit controller is this

```
public ActionResult AddEditRecord(tblEquipment Equipment, string cmd, string mode)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                switch (cmd)
                {
                    case "Add":
                        try
                        {
                            db.tblEquipments.Add(Equipment);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return RedirectToAction(mode);
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                    case "Update":
                        try
                        {
                            tblEquipment Item = db.tblEquipments.Where(m => m.ID == Equipment.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (Item != null)
                            {
                                Item.AssetNo = Equipment.AssetNo;
                                Item.MachineName = Equipment.MachineName;
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            return RedirectToAction(mode);
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_AddEdit", Equipment);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("AddEdit", Equipment);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is here:

```
@Html.Hidden("hidMode", Request.QueryString["mode"].ToString())
```

You give name `hidMode` to hidden field and expect it as `cmd` in your controller. So either rename hidden field or rename input parameter in a controller action